# MySQL CONCAT href - greater/less than signs showing as &gt; &lt; in HTML code instead of > <

Tags: mysql, hyperlink, concatenation, href

I'm trying to create a hyperlinked field in a MySQL SELECT using CONCAT, but the value is not showing as a hyperlink, but as the literal href statement on the page.  The HTML being displayed on the page looks correct:

```
\<a href="http://example.com:4200/event/view/4601">4601\</a>
```

But I noticed in the HTML, and I think this is the issue, the greater than and less than signs are showing as > and < instead of > and <:

```
&lt;a href="http://example.com:4200/event/view/4601"&gt;4601&lt;/a&gt;
```

My question is, how do I get the greater than and less than signs to show as > and < instead of > and < given the following SQL CONCAT statement?:

```
CONCAT('\<a href="http://example.com:4200/event/view/',e.event_id,'">',e.event_id,'\</a>') AS 'Event-ID',
```

So the Event-ID field shows, or should show a hyperlink.

Comment: This sounds like it is to do with how your results are being rendered, rather than the database.  What code are you using to display the results fetched from the database?

Comment: Need to validate your variables.  Are you just dumping line code into the MySQL server, or are you using DBEAVER or WorkBench?  Cause if you are not doing that, it is like using notepad to edit an excel file instead of Excel, its possible, but 10 times more difficult. Did I mentioned they are free?

Comment: your sql will be returning `<` and `>`; something you are doing to it is changing those to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.  for help with that, you will need to show your code.

Comment: Here is a snippet of the JS code forming the SQL statement:


 let sql = `SELECT
  e.event_id as 'id',
  CONCAT('<a href="http://example.com:4200/event/view/',e.event_id,'">',e.event_id,'</a>') AS 'Event-ID',
  e.parent_event_id AS 'Parent Event',